# AJAX request makes two POST queries (Play framework)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, playframework-2.0

I have form template like this

```
@(list: List[Item])

@main("test form") {
<form id="testForm" action="@routes.Application.accept()" method="post">
    <table align="center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>mark</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for(item <- list) {
                <tr>
                <td>@item.name</td>
                <td><input type="text" title="@item.name" id="@item.id" value="@item.mark"></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onClick="sendJSON('@routes.Application.accept()')">Send</button>
</form>
}
```

And on the server side - something like this

```
public static Result getForm() {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Item item = new Item(i + 1, "person " + (i + 1), (i % 5) + 1);
        items.add(item);
    }
    return ok(form.render(items));
}

public static Result accept() {
    DynamicForm form = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
    String json = form.get("json");
    if (null == json) {
        json = "Nothing received!";
    }
    Logger.info(json);      
    return ok(result.render(json));
}
```

Javascript function sendJSON() is

```
function sendJSON(serverUrl) {
// making JSON
        jsonObj = [];
        $("input[type=text]").each(function() {

            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var title = $(this).attr("title");
            var mark = $(this).val();

            item = {}
            item ["id"] = id;
            item ["title"] = title;
            item ["mark"] = mark;

            jsonObj.push(item);
        });
        var jsonString = 'json=' + JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
        alert(jsonString);
// sending
        $.ajax({
            url: serverUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: jsonString,
            success: function(res){
                $('html').html(res);
                alert("done!");
            },
            failure: function(res){
                alert("failure!");
            }
        });
        return false;
};
```

in logger I see two records for one AJAX request. One with JSON data, but another is "Nothing received!". What is the best way to send only one POST query? Why alerts "done!" and "failure!" doesn't appear?

Thanks for wasting your time for me. Best regards.

Comment: You dont need to specify `data: 'json='+JSON.stringify'` it brakes the json format. Just send `data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj)`

Comment: What if I want to pass JSON string as POST request parameter?

Comment: Oh ok, my bad. I don't see why you would do this but you can ^^

Answer (score 0):

I found other way to perform `$.ajax` POST request on the form submission. I wrote ajax.js in which I placed this code

```
// this function makes JSON data and send to the server POST request
function sendPost(requestUrl) {
// make JSON
        jsonObj = [];
        $("input:text").each(function() {

            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var title = $(this).attr("title");
            var mark = $(this).val();

            item = {}
            item ["id"] = id;
            item ["title"] = title;
            item ["mark"] = mark;

            jsonObj.push(item);
        });
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
        alert(jsonString);
// send to server
        $.ajax({
            url : requestUrl,
            type : 'POST',
            data : { marks : jsonString },
            success : function(res) {
                $('html').fadeOut(function() {
                    $(this).html(res).fadeIn();
                });
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR.statusText + " (" + jqXHR.status + ") " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
                alert("Load error!");
            }
        });
}

// And this one - select form with id='testForm' 
// and runs sendPost function on the submit event.
// to prevent regular form POST request - e.preventDefault is used.
$('#testForm').submit(function(e) {
    var requestUrl = $(this).attr('action');
    sendPost(requestUrl);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And in the template I replaced tag `<button>...</button>` to `<input type="submit"...>`